# Create an Alias using Apache's mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, alias

I need to create an alias for one exact page which unfortunately special characters in it. I do have an environment set up so other redirects work fine, but not this one:

```
RewriteRule ^/ow/email.htm?who=Kate%20Jones&direct=True&directemail=kate.jones@google.com$    http://www.google.com/ow/lalala.htm
```

How should I rewrite this statement so that it works?

PS. This is my first time here so do let me know if I'm not following stackoverflow policy correctly or smth ;) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [`RewriteCond` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) for the URI query, either to examine *QUERY_STRING*:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =who=Kate%20Jones&direct=True&directemail=kate.jones@google.com
RewriteRule ^/ow/email\.htm$ http://www.google.com/ow/lalala.htm
```

Or the [request line](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1) in *THE_REQUEST*:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /ow/email\.htm\?who=Kate%20Jones&direct=True&directemail=kate\.jones@google.com\s
RewriteRule ^/ow/email\.htm$ http://www.google.com/ow/lalala.htm
```

Comment: Works like charm! Thank you so much for explaining how powerful mod_rewrite works!